# Locking controls on the canvas in a form editor in WPF

Tags: wpf, locking, controls

I am building a form editor in WPF. One of the features we need in it is to let the user "lock" one or more controls on the canvas. By locking I mean the user would not be able to move, resize or modify other properties of the control.

I have tried with `ContentControl` but did not get the results I am looking for.

Comment: Which specific controls do you need to lock down?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you saying that you're using WPF to create an editor that allows users to create forms of some variety? Or are you saying you're writing a... WPF editor?

Comment: @RandomEngy. I have some custom controls derived from Button, Label etc. These control behave more or less like the parent controls they are derived from but have some additional properties.

Comment: @Tim. Thats correct. I am creating a form builder that allows user to put (custom) controls on the canvas and move them around. just like visual studio's form editor.

Comment: @user559788 - So then... you wrote the code to allow them to move the controls around, right? So shouldn't you be able to just turn that off when they lock a control? Maybe I'm still confused what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Tim. The form editor is very generic in nature. It has a canvas as its base and any control can be placed on it. Not all the controls need to be locked. only the ones that user wants and I am trying to find a way to put that logic/behavior in the control itself not in the form.

Comment: The control does not control its placement.  Please post the code where a control is placed on the canvas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should use the `IsEnabled` property. Basic controls with interaction have this, and you can expose it on your custom controls as well and pass the property down.

If something is set with `IsEnabled = false` it will be grayed out and cannot be affected by user input.

Comment: but I can still move the control around, resize it etc. in the design mode.

Comment: What's "design mode"? Do you own the code that places the controls on the canvas and allows the user to move them?

Comment: Hi RandomEngy, Yes I do "own" the design code. Its an open source project that I started with and your comment makes perfect sense. I did find a way to disable movement of controls on the design surface when they are in "locked" state. How do I mark your comment as an answer?